# How to get the device cpu architecture in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, cpu-architecture

I want to get the CPU architecture information of the device (Android and iOS).

I tried some packages like [system_info2](https://pub.dev/packages/system_info2) and [system_info_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/system_info_fetch) but they didn't work for me.

Comment: what is your problem with these packages?

Comment: They dose not support the iOS device

Comment: Add more detail to your question to stop downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `device_info_plus` package to retrieve the CPU architecture.

```dart
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
  print('CPU architecture: ${androidInfo.supportedAbis}');
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
  print('CPU architecture: ${iosInfo.utsname.machine}');
}
```